# SQL Server : count() for each group, but only groups having 1+ element like... AND all elements like

Tags: sql-server

There are tables(and columns) like:

- `Clients` (clientID)
- `Houses` (houseID)
- `Visits` (clientID, houseID, visit_date)
- `Contracts` (contractID, houseID, clientID, rentDate_from, rentDate_end)

I have problem with writing a SQL query of this kind:

- how many visits to houses did each client, before renting one of them?

It's easy to count total number of visits for each client, listing all visits + group by `clientID` and selecting `count(*)` for each group.

Let's say this is select_1, and select_2 is listing all contracts for all clients.

Select_1 is not answer, because count must be performed only on groups, which:

- have at least 1 row "like" row in select_2 (it means that at least one of visited houses was rented, because it can happen that client visited few houses, but rented other, not visited house). my idea for this is comparing select_1 and select_2 with:

  where s1.clientID = s2.clientID and s1.houseID = s2.houseID
- each group must have all rows(visits) with date of same day or earlier than contract date

  maybe: `datediff(day, s1.visit_date, s2.rentDate_from) >= 0`

(why after pressing enter there is 1 empty line on this forum?)

Comment: This sounds more like you're giving us requirements and asking us to write it for you.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A `HAVING` clause serves to filter groups from an aggregate query.  It is similar to a `WHERE` clause, but applies to the aggregate result.  In this particular case, it also turns out that you want to use essentially the same query both to form the initial result rows and also to filter the groups; for SQL Server, a `WITH` clause allows you to perform that query once and reuse it.  Thus, you might end up with something like this:

```
WITH previousVisits(clientId, houseId_visited, houseId_rented) AS 
  SELECT Visits.clientId, Visits.houseId, Contracts.houseId
    FROM Visits
      JOIN Contracts ON Visits.clientId = Contracts.clientId
    WHERE Visits.visit_date <= Contracts.rentDate_from
SELECT clientId, houseId_rented, COUNT(*) AS visitCount
  FROM previousVisits pv1
  GROUP BY clientId, houseId_rented
  HAVING houseId_rented IN (
    SELECT houseId_visited
      FROM previousVisits pv2
      WHERE
        pv2.clientId = clientId
        AND pv2.houseId_rented = houseId_rented
  )
```

Note that you should consider whether this does what you want in the case that the same client rents two different houses.  As written, for each house rented it will count all houses visited before that rental.  Even then there is a potential issue if the same client rents the same house more than once.

Comment: Thanks for answer and introduction + example of using WITH. Your query needed analysing and little changes to give correct results, which i belive was concious move from your side;)

Answer (score 0):

My query with simpler commands:

select distinct

```
co.clientID,
(
 select count(*) from Visits vi
 where vi.clientID = co.clientID  and  vi.visit_date <= co.rentDate_from
)
```

from Contracts co

where co.clientID in

```
    (
     select vi.clientID from Visits vi
     where vi.houseID = co.houseID  and  vi.clientID = co.clientID  and
           vi.visit_date <= co.rentDate_from    
    )
```

J.B. version after changes:

WITH previousVisits(clientId, houseId_visited, houseId_rented) AS

->  SELECT distinct Visits.clientId, Visits.houseId, Contracts.houseId

```
FROM Visits

  JOIN Contracts ON Visits.clientId = Contracts.clientId

WHERE Visits.visit_date <= Contracts.rentDate_from
```

SELECT clientId, houseId_rented, COUNT(*) AS visitCount

FROM previousVisits pv1

GROUP BY clientId, houseId_rented

HAVING houseId_rented IN (

```
SELECT houseId_visited

  FROM previousVisits

  WHERE
```

->       clientId = pv.1clientId

->        AND houseId_rented = pv1.houseId_rented

)